# nvm-windows has failed to run the latest nodejs version 8.11.2

Tags: node.js

I have used nvm-window tool to successful install nodejs v6.11.4 (old version) but it has failed for the latest nodejs version. Got this error while installing the v8.11.2. as shown by the screenshot.
[nvm install errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FV0qb.png)

```
Downloading node.js version 8.11.2 (64-bit)...
Error while downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.11.2/win-x64//node.exe - stream error: stream ID 7; INTERNAL_ERROR
```

when i try to run node -v command to check nodejs version. This is the error i get.

```
Program 'node.exe' failed to run: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.At line:1
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally the problem was solved when this node js version v8.11.3 lts was released.
I can now use my npm to install the nodejs modules.

```
PS C:\Users\goldsoft25\AppData\Roaming\nvm> nvm list
8.11.3
```

`* 6.11.4 (Currently using 64-bit executable)`